# returns 503 Service Unavailable status, if login_check fails - symfony2

Tags: authentication, symfony, firewall

I'm developing a web app using Symfony2 as the framework, in which user needs to login to use rest of the service. I'm using symfony's firewall to authenticate user.

firewall code is

```
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    login:
        pattern:  ^/login$
        security: false

    secured_area:
        pattern:    ^/
        form_login: ~
        logout: ~
```

Controller code is

```
public function indexAction()
{
    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('index_search'));
}

public function loginAction() {

    $request = $this->getRequest();
    $session = $request->getSession();

    // get the login error if there is one
    if ($request->attributes->has(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR)) {
        $error = $request->attributes->get(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
    } else {
        $error = $session->get(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
        $session->remove(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
    }

    return $this->render('IsBeagleBundle:Auth:login.html.php', array(
        // last username entered by the user
        'last_username' => $session->get(SecurityContext::LAST_USERNAME),
        'error'         => $error,
    ));
}
```

Routes are

```
$collection->add('index', new Route('/', array(
    '_controller' => 'IsBeagleBundle:Auth:index',
)));

$collection->add('login', new Route('/login', array(
    '_controller' => 'IsBeagleBundle:Auth:login',
)));
$collection->add('login_check', new Route('/login_check', array()));
```

The problem i'm facing is

If the firewall authentication passes, the redirection works perfectly and goes to the search page, but if the authentication fails it returns with `503 Service Unavailable` status, where it should go for the login page again.

But if i refresh the empty page, then it displays the login page.

Can anyone figure out what i was doing wrong?

**EDIT 1 - output**

[image]

**EDIT 2**

If i comment out the following line on the front controller `app.php`,

```
$kernel = new AppCache($kernel);
```

then the status returned is changed to `200`, but took long waiting time and response is empty. Other thing i figured out is, if i try to print the symfony session variable within the login controller

```
$request = $this->getRequest();
$session = $request->getSession();

echo '<pre>';
print_r($session);
echo '</pre>';
```

it take too much time and memory, and never ends. which causes the browser to freeze. I couldn't find out the reason.

***P.S : I'm using symfony standard distribution***

Comment: What is the url that is shown when the 503 error appears?

Comment: @CarlosGranados look at my updated image

Comment: OK, so the redirection is working. Can you maybe try the use_forward configuration option for the firewall and see if this does not produce the error? This option makes the firewall not send a redirect but rather forward the request to the corresponding controller, see http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html

Comment: @CarlosGranados same result, no improvement

Comment: What are you doing with the 'error' variable? Are you displaying it? Can you maybe try to remove the code that gets the error and see if the 503 is still there?

Comment: @CarlosGranados nothing doing, but same result. i just followed the documentation.

Comment: Yes, your code seems correct, I was just trying to figure out what could be different in the case where authentication fails

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `$` from the `^/login$` pattern for it to match everything that begins with `/login`.

Comment: No, then it will throw `Unable to find the controller for path "/login_check"` exception. By the way i'm glad to say i'm using your `blowfish encoder bundle` as the encoder in my project.